# Pipe between 2 Windows Services C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, pipe, named-pipes

Is there any way to build and connect two Windows Services through a pipe(anonymous or named)? The first service waits for a custom command and when the user inputs that through a windows form app, the first service sends that command through a pipe to the second service. The second service waits for the command and when receives it, it creates a file with that command.My issue is to create pipe between Windows Service Applications not WCF Service Application.

I need to achieve this using C# Windows Service Application, not WCF Service Application!

Comment: Why you need two windows service ? As Carrvin has mentioned, you can host a WCF service(with two methods) in windows service and from client app call the first method and it will call the second method which will create the file ?

Comment: 7 years later, did you find a solution for this? MS documentation is in C++ and I could not find a good tutorial in C#. Just need a way for my two Windows services to communicate with each other. How hard is it? I can still use APIs but I am looking for a Windows recommended way for local communication.

Answer (score -1):

What you are requesting is possible.

Here is a basic tutorial for building up wcf-services (and -clients):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tutorial describes about hosting a WCF service library in windows service and then invoking the WCF from client app. What OP wanted is a inter communication between two windows services.

Comment: The tutorial also describes a bidirectional communication of wcf-services and the problem of OP can be solved by creating an application which has a client- and a server-part...

Comment: My issue is to create pipe between Windows Service Applications not WCF  Service Application.

Comment: The easiest way to communicate between two services is to use a WCF-Service which can be hosted in your windows service. Just check it out and you will get an easy solution in a short period of time;)

Comment: Let me see if I understood.. So, basically, I create two windows services that reference to two WCF-services and the pipe between the 2 windows services will be created using their referenced WCF-services?

Comment: You can set up two windows-services. The first on which writes down the document, has to host a wcf-service and the other one which should call the other service over pipe has to 'host' a wcf-client.